# Post JSON variable with jquery

Tags: jquery, json

I'm using YQl to parse some content from another domain. YQL returns me json result and i want to post is to a php file?

```
$.ajax({
    url: urele,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'callback',
    jsonpCallback: 'cbfunc',
    success: function(data) {
        $.post( "get.php", { "pst": data }, function( res ) {
            console.log(res);
        },"json");
    }
});
```

Ajax works perfect but $.post...
What's wrong?

Comment: @Kevin B: 1. why do you think it needs to be parsed? 2. Why do you think we have idea what `data` contains/should contain?

Comment: @KevinB I'm guessing he's being facetious, only pointing out that without more context, such as an idea of what kind of error is being thrown, what kind of data the OP is getting back, etc, we're all just spitballing in the dark...

Comment: @Kevin B: "You can't simply post a deeply nested object as a post value" --- you actually can http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: @Kevin B: I'm not sure what is a "deeply nested object". Neither javascript (ecmascript) or json define such a term.

Comment: You have a `console.log(res)`. What does it spit out?

Comment: @Kevin B: **any js object** can be sent via jquery's `$.post()` without any additional processing. So not sure what your statement "it has to be converted to a string" is based on

Comment: @user3204567: the `console.log` line wasn't run then. It cannot print "nothing"

Comment: Can you run `console.log(data)` directly before the `$.post` to see what is being returned?

Answer (score 0):

run your data object through `$.params`, to see if it serializing your object correctly, or inspect the Chrome network tab to see what jQuery is doing.

I don't know how you need to send the object, it depends on what the backend expects in terms of hydrating the post body into an object.

jQuery serializes objects in the format `property[key/index]=value`